# Can I have an MVP list use a List inside a model?

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I know I can have an MVP list like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<PublicationSystem.ViewModels.ProfileSnapshotViewModel>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Salutation)
        </th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Salutation)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

But I'd like to use a model like this:

```
public class ProfileSnapshotListViewModel
{
    public Guid ResourceAssignedToId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<PublicationSystem.ViewModels.ProfileSnapshotViewModel> Snapshots { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to have my view end up like this:

```
@model PublicationSystem.ViewModels.ProfileSnapshotListViewModel

<div id="pnlResourceSnapshotEdit">
    @{ Html.RenderAction("_ResourceSnapshotEdit", "Profiles", new { id = Model.ResourceAssignedToId }); }
</div>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Snapshots.Salutation)
        </th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model.Snapshots) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Salutation)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Can I use a model like that for a list? Is this possible? How would I set up the list to use the Snapshots list?

Comment: I'm not understanding the question, Yes you can use View Models that contain lists and loop through them in the views. what errors are you facing?

Comment: Of course you can. Did you even try it? If your models `Snapshots` property is initialized and contains `ProfileSnapshotViewModel` objects, the code you have shown will work fine (except for the `<th>` element which will need to be `@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Snapshots.FirstOrDefault().Salutation)`)

Comment: `@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Snapshots.Salutation)` does not work. Yes I tried it. How can I set the table header data (`<th>`) with the child table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing it like this:

```
@model PublicationSystem.ViewModels.ProfileSnapshotListViewModel

<div id="pnlResourceSnapshotEdit">
    @{ Html.RenderAction("_ResourceSnapshotEdit", "Profiles", new { id = Model.ResourceAssignedToId }); }
</div>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Snapshots.FirstOrDefault().Salutation)
        </th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model.Snapshots) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Salutation)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

This gave me the headers and items as I wanted.

What I was looking for was:

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Snapshots.FirstOrDefault().Salutation)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's certainly possible.  You almost have it syntactically correct.  With Razor, you need to use a `for` loop, to keep a reference back to your model, so that Razor knows how to build your model back up:

```
@for(int i = 0; i < Model.Snapshots.Length; i++) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Snapshots[i].Salutation)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: OP's `foreach` loop is fine. You only need a `for` loop when generating form controls (so that they are correctly named with indexers)

Comment: Still looking on how to define the TH/column headings.